# How SQL rearranges query result when ordered by date where all the columns have same date

Tags: mysql, date, sql-order-by

InSQL, I have a table with 2 rows in which i have a date column and an integer column and a varchar column. Date field and integer field have exactly same values for both the rows, only varchar field differs. Data is like below

```
no   date     message
1   1/1/2000    a
1   1/1/2000    b
```

When i query like

search * from table_name order by no,
query result is same as it is already there in the table

```
no   date     message
1   1/1/2000    a
1   1/1/2000    b
```

i.e i can rerieve the data in the same order when i order by integer value

But when i try to order by date field( which is exactly same)
then i get like this

```
no   date     message
1   1/1/2000    b
1   1/1/2000    a
```

It rearranges the rows. Why does this happen

Answer (score 0):

A "stable sort" is a sort that preserves the original order of rows in the data being sorted when keys have the same values ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) has a page devoted to these algorithms).  So, you are asking about whether or not sorts in SQL are stable (or why they are not).

The answer is obvious:  sorts in SQL cannot be stable.  Why is this obvious?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no ordering in the table to preserve.

If you want to preserve an "original ordering", you need to include an additional unique key that specifies the original ordering.  If you have an auto-incremented primary key, then that would be a natural key to add to your `order by`:  `order by date, no`.

Comment: Why it preserves order for columns with type not as date and why its not for columns with date type

Comment: @user2971184 . . . It is not preserving order *ever* for tied keys.  Sometimes the resulting order may be what you expect; that is a coincidence.